# How do I have names of groups in columns and summarize values?

Tags: sql, sas

Sorry, not sure how to best word this so I'll just give an example.

```
1  VA b x 10
2  VA g y  5
3  VA b x  6
4  VA s y  7
5  VA s x  8
6  PA b y  1
7  PA s x  4
8  PA g y  5
9  PA s x  6
10 PA b y  9
```

I would like to summarize the above data like the following:

```
       x_b    x_s     x_g     y_b    y_s    y_g
VA     16       8      0      9      7      0
PA      0      10      0      9      0      5
```

where I have a row for each state and combinations of the two groups (group of x, y and group of b,s,g) across the top and summarize the values for all groupings like that.

What is the best way to do this in SQL?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this data in a table?  What columns exist in that table?  Are there limitations on the values that can exist in any of the columns?

Comment: yes the data is in a table. Just wanna summarize on those 5 columns. No limitations on values. Thanks,

Comment: Why the SQL limitation? SQL is the absolute worst way to do this in SAS. Also, really would rather see some evidence you've tried to solve the problem rather than just asking for someone to do it for you in questions posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
proc sql;
    select state,
           sum(case when col3 = 'b' and col4 = 'x' then col5 else 0 end) as x_b,
           sum(case when col3 = 's' and col4 = 'x' then col5 else 0 end) as x_s,
           sum(case when col3 = 'g' and col4 = 'x' then col5 else 0 end) as x_g,
           sum(case when col3 = 's' and col4 = 'y' then col5 else 0 end) as y_s,
           sum(case when col3 = 'g' and col4 = 'y' then col5 else 0 end) as y_g
    from t
    group by state;
```

Comment: Thanks! this is the right idea. but When I do this in SAS as proc sql, it does not aggregate the values for each state under each group... it creates multiple rows for each state where there is only one value for one column per each row and everything else zero. Any ideas?

Comment: Should those be Sum(col5) ?

Comment: Sum(col5) doesn't do it. I had to do it in two steps: first the above without the group by and then another one where I do a sum on each group created by state. Thanks!!

Comment: Ugg, while this is technically right it's a terrible way to solve the problem.  SQL is not the right tool here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this in SQL.  You're in SAS, use the tools you have: here `PROC TABULATE` is the best tool.

```
data have;
input obs state $ var1 $ var2 $ val;
datalines;
1  VA b x 10
2  VA g y  5
3  VA b x  6
4  VA s y  7
5  VA s x  8
6  PA b y  1
7  PA s x  4
8  PA g y  5
9  PA s x  6
10 PA b y  9 
;;;;
run;

proc tabulate data=have;
  class state var1 var2;
  var val;
  tables state, var1=' '*var2=' '*val=' '*sum=' '/printmiss misstext='0';
run;
```

If you want a dataset and not a printed table, that's easy enough to do.  Just make a dataset from TABULATE, then make a few minor changes and transpose it.

```
proc tabulate data=have out=want_first;
  class state var1 var2;
  var val;
  tables state, var1=' '*var2=' '*val=' '*sum=' '/printmiss misstext='0';
run;

data want_pret;
  set want_first;
  var_name = catx('_',var2,var1);
  value    = coalesce(val_sum,0);
  keep state var_name value;
run;

proc transpose data=want_pret out=want;
  by state;
  id var_name;
  var value;
run;
```

Notice that none of this requires hardcoding the values for any of the variables - no matter what you put in var1/var2, this will always give you the right result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a cross-tab use `PROC FREQ`. Use the WEIGHT statement to pass in the exiting counts and the SPARSE option to get the zeros output.

```
proc freq data=have ;
  tables state*v2*v1 / noprint out=counts sparse ;
  weight cnt ;
run;
```

You can then turn the result into your horizontal format by using `PROC TRANSPOSE`.

```
proc transpose data=counts delimiter=_ 
 out=want(drop= _name_ _label_)
;
  by state ;
  id v2 v1 ;
  var count ;
run;
```

[image]